# Python - Declare two variable with the same values at the same time

Tags: python, python-3.x, declaration, declare

```
a=[1,2,3]
b=[1,2,3]
```

Is there a way to do this on one line? (obviously not with ";")

```
a,b=[1,2,3]
```

doesn't work because of

```
a,b,c=[1,2,3]
```

a=1
b=2
c=3

Comment: Do you want them to point to different objects or as aliases?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
In [18]: a,b=[1,2,3],[1,2,3]

In [19]: a
Out[19]: [1, 2, 3]

In [20]: b
Out[20]: [1, 2, 3]
```

you may also want to do this:

```
In [22]: a=b=[1,2,3]

In [23]: a
Out[23]: [1, 2, 3]

In [24]: b
Out[24]: [1, 2, 3]
```

but be careful that, `a is b` is `True` in this case, namely, `a` is just a reference of `b`

Answer (score 7):

```
a,b,c = [[1,2,3] for _ in range(3)]
```

each points to a different object

Answer (score 5):

Edit: as found by DSM in order for the following lines to work you need to declare b as a list in order for my code to work (so this is no longer on one line, but I will leave it here as a reference). Changed the order as suggested by Paulo Bu

```
a=[1,2,3]
b=a[:]
```

Old code:

```
b=[]
a=b[:]=[1,2,3]
```

This assigns the values to b and then copies all the values from b to a.

If you do it like this:

```
a=b=[1,2,3]
```

and then change

```
b[1] = 0
```

a would also be changed

Comment: This will raise a `NameError` unless `b` already exists (and requires b to be a list).

Comment: Indeed, I missed that one too :)

Comment: I think so far the best way is this answer but doing: `a=[1,2,3];b=a[:]`. The statements in that order seem more logical and less complicated.

Comment: @wnnmaw only if you already have a declared as a list (try del a)

Comment: whoops, and this is why you shouldn't test multiple things back to back.  Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: PauloBu, yes that looks more logical, I'll adapt my answer. wnnmaw, Guilty as well :). In the end it looks like gravetii's answer is the only one-line option.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> a = b = [1, 2, 3]
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]
>>> b
[1, 2, 3]
>>> b = [3, 2, 1]
>>> b
[3, 2, 1]
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: This results in a change because you're essentially redefining `b` with the above example.  Using `a.pop(1)` as stated below shows the relation between the two.

Answer (score 1):

`a,b = [1,2,3],[1,2,3]` does it in one line and points to different objects.

`a=b=[1,2,3]` is clear but points to the same object.

Try `a.pop(1)` in both cases and you will see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Note... this solution
    a=b=[1,2,3]

results in assigning the same (mutable) list to ivar's a and b. The original question shows 2 different lists being assigned to a & b.

This solution suffers the same problem:

```
>>> a,b = ([1,2,3],)*2
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]
>>> b
[1, 2, 3]
>>> b.append(4)
>>> b
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```